# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory for logging in multiprocess(gunicorn) environment python

Tags: python, logging

I have using gunicorn to create my server and logging my file using python logging package. But when I am running gunicorn with 100 worker nodes with RotatingfileHandler I am seeing following error.

```
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/logging/handlers.py", line 70, in emit
    self.doRollover()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/logging/handlers.py", line 171, in doRollover
    self.rotate(self.baseFilename, dfn)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/logging/handlers.py", line 111, in rotate
    os.rename(source, dest)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/log/logging_info.log' -> '/tmp/log/logging_info.log.1'
Call stack:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 890, in _bootstrap
    self._bootstrap_inner()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
```

Following is my logging config file

```
version: 1

formatters:
  simple:
    format: "%(asctime)s %(funcName)s %(levelname)s %(message)s"

handlers:
  log_handler:
    class: logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler
    level: DEBUG
    backupCount: 1
    maxBytes: 104857600 # 100MB
    filename: /tmp/log/logging_info.log
    formatter: simple
loggers:
    logger:
        handlers: [log_handler]
        level: DEBUG
```

I am using to create log files.

```
logging.config.dictConfig(config)
```

Consider my server code simply writes into log files

```
import logging
from flask import Flask, request, Response, jsonify
logger = logging.getLogger("logger")
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/myapp", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def call():
    logger.info('Fill it with garbage')
create_app():
    return app
```

I am running the above code with gunicorn server using command

```
gunicorn 'create_app()' --worker-class gevent -w 100 --bind localhost:5000
```

Answer (score -1):

`logging.config.dictConfig(config)` - it doesnt create a directory. Please check, do you have this /tmp/log/ directory?

Comment: I've already created a directory. If you've read the error from my post `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/log/logging_info.log' -> '/tmp/log/logging_info.log.1'
` It clearly path exists and error is at time of Rollover.

Comment: ok, I see the error. But it means that log file doesnt exist)) So, try to increase the count of ```backupCount: 1``` May be race condition of log files is here.